# How do I print the size of my ArrayList before entering any values?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, project

System.out.println("Enter the number of elements needed: " );

```
    System.out.printf("Enter value 1: ");
    value.add(in.nextInt());
```

How do I print the size of my ArrayList before entering any values?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be empty?

Comment: An ARRAY would have a fixed size. An ArrayList, however, grows dynamically to hold however many things you add to it.

Comment: What good world printing the size do? You need to enter the limit then check against that limit while entering values.

Comment: "on our task, we have to type in a size first before inputting any values, like of i type 5, the list only accept 5 values." So get your size from the user then use a `for` or `while` loop to get that many inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can call `.size()` on any list at any time, but prior to adding any values it will return 0

Comment: on our task, we have to type in a size first before inputting any values, like of i type 5, the list only accept 5 values.

Answer (score 0):

In Java ArrayList is dynamic so if you haven't added any values into it the size is 0.

Comment: on our task, we have to type in a size first before inputting any values, like of i type 5, the list only accept 5 values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> on our task, we have to type in a size first before inputting any
> values, like of i type 5, the list only accept 5 values.

So get your size from the user, then use a for or while loop to get that many inputs.

Something like:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of elements needed: ");
int size = in.nextInt();
for(int i=1; i <= size; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter value " + i + ": ");
    value.add(in.nextInt());
}
```